# Sticky Navigation Not so sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

My sticky navigation worked fine until I uploaded it to the server. Now the navigation doesn't stick to the stop, and the logo image appears to be behind one of the content DIVS. Please any help would be most helpful thank you.

http://christophersharrett.com/

Comment: $('.nav').scrollToFixed(); thats your problem.. scrollToFixed has not loaded yet therefore erroring.

Comment: Yeah, looks like some part of the script that makes it "sticky" isn't loaded. The browser doesn't know what "position: webkit sticky;" is.

Comment: his references give a 404 as well especially the one which is called jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js so that is the problem here lol

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your `$('.nav').scrollToFixed();` has not loaded yet 
therefore erroring - so `scrollToFixed()` function does not exist

if you look in your console log this file is returning a 404:

```
jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js
```

you are referring

```
<script src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which is

```
http://christophersharrett.com/js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js = 404 (can not be found)
```

you need to make sure that your script is in a `js` folder in that structure on the server for it to work. Find where that script is and either change your reference above or move it to the correct file structure.